# index out of range in for loop, unable to know how many items will be returned

Tags: c#

I'm trying to take a string, check if they have parentheses or brackets in them, check if those contain numbers inside, and return true if it does.

I'm using `Any(char.IsDigit)` to check if there is a digit but it still returns `true` if there are just letters and no digits.

Also I keep getting an error that the index is out of bounds. I will be using different strings so I can't use a fixed number for the bounds. I'm checking that it is not `null` in the for loop before going to the next one, but maybe thats not how Im supposed to do it?

**Code**

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{            
    string test = "Endometrial cancer is the most common gynecologic malignancy in the developed world[1], with the highest incidence in the US and Canada[2]. Endometrial biopsy plays a significant role in early cancer diagnosis, preoperative assessment, and treatment planning[3, 4], with Pipelle biopsy emerging as the most common method for sampling endometrial tissue in patients with suspected endometrial cancer[5, 6]. Pipelle sampling is a cost-effective[7] procedure and has similar sampling adequacy and histopathological results as dilation and curettage (DC)[8].";

    bool brackets = hasRef(test, '[', ']');
    bool parantheses = hasRef(test, '(', ')');

    Console.WriteLine(brackets);
    Console.WriteLine(parantheses);

}

static bool hasRef(string s, char p1, char p2)
{
    bool has = false;

    for (int i = 1; (i <= 20 && ((s.Split(p1, p2)[i]) != null)); i += 2)
    {
        string split = s.Split(p1, p2)[i];
        Console.WriteLine(p1 + split);
        if (split.Any(char.IsDigit))
        {
            has = true;
            Console.WriteLine(split);
            break;
        }
    }

    return has;
}
```

**Error**

> Exception in user code:
>
> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
>          at Rextester.Program.hasRef(String s, Char p1, Char p2)
>          at Rextester.Program.Main(String[] args)

Comment: *"I'm trying to take a string, check if they have parentheses or brackets in them, check if those contain numbers inside, and return true if it does"* That horribly complicated `for` loop can be replaced by a simple Regex.

Comment: What does your magic number `20` represent? It seems like that's the problem. Perhaps you should either `Split` first so you know the `Length` (and so you only do it once instead of every iteration), or use some other method, like `IndexOf` or, as Ron said, `Regex`

Comment: 20 is just a random number. Im not that familiar with Regex, can you help me with the code? Or is there a way to split and get all the returned items at once and store them in an array or something?

Comment: To get past your initial error, first do: `string[] items = s.Split(p1, p2);` Then you can loop over the length of the array: `for (int i = 1; i < items.Length; i += 2) { ... }`

Comment: Here's one way to do it: `private static bool HasRef(string s, char p1, char p2) { var result = false; var secondIndex = -1; do { var firstIndex = s.IndexOf(p1, secondIndex + 1); if (firstIndex == -1) break; secondIndex = s.IndexOf(p2, firstIndex + 1);  if (secondIndex == -1) break; var contents = s.Substring(firstIndex + 1, secondIndex - firstIndex - 1); Console.WriteLine($"Found item: {p1}{contents}{p2}"); if (contents.Any(char.IsNumber))
{ result = true; } } while (s.Length > secondIndex + 1); return result; 
}`